# Get unique data from a field using ElasticSearch query DSL in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch

I have already various queries that collect data and show it in the Kibana dashboard. 
Now I would like to get unique values from my result data. How can I write the query DSL for that.

Basically I would like to get unique value for the field contextMap.connectionid. Is there a way do achieve that using something similar to this example?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "app",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "app.key": "contextMap.connectionid"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is contextMap a nested field? What is its relationship with the app field?

Comment: Could you post your mapping GET <your_index_name>/_mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate distinct count with the help of aggregation . 
So, your search query is :

Search Query :

```
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "app",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "app.key": "contextMap.connectionid"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
        "uniqueconnectionId": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "contextMap.connectionid.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer here for calculating distinct values of a field https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-distinct-values-from-a-field-in-elasticsearch/99783

Comment: @Dev.User993 it would be helpful if you can give mapping of the index, then I can test it more accurately. Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments. How can I find the mapping of the index? I would gladly provide if I knew what it was.

Comment: You can send a GET request to this API  <your_index_name>/_mapping. In place of this <your_index_name> put your Elasticsearch index name . Response would be mapping of the same.